# PCA Reconstruction: statsmodels vs sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am trying to move my PCA model from sklearn to statmodels.

Using **sklearn**, I can reconstruct my data in the following manner:

```
# reconstruction using 2 principal components
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)

# reconstruct the data
X_reconst = np.dot(pca.transform(X)[:,:2], pca.components_[:2,:])
```

What would be the equivalent of doing the same in **statsmodels**?
The API and nomenclature seem to be quite different.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `fa` here ?

Comment: @MohammedKashif sorry, just a mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statsmodels PCA implementation saves the projection of data as a model attribute.

For example,

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

# specifying two components and fitting data
pca = sm.PCA(X, ncomp=2)
X_reconst = pca.projection
```